# My Java install is broken

Tags: 11.10, java, openjdk

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and was noticing that Java was not working on a few websites and ran a check:

> keith@KD-PB:~$ java -version
>
> java version "1.5.0"
>
> gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.6.1
>
> Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There
>   is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

So I uninstalled my Java (OpenJDK 1.6.0 according to Ubuntu Software Centre) and reinstalled it and all the dependicies. So tried checking I had the right Java package installed;

> keith@KD-PB:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
>
> There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/bin/gij-4.6
>
> Nothing to configure.

So now I am scratching my head and not sure what is wrong. I have installed Oracle's JRE 6 and it works straight away, so what could be wrong with the OpenJDK?

Thanks

UPDATE - From some suggestions I inputted the following and think there is a problem with where /etc/alternatives/java is pointing;

> keith@KD-PB:~$ ls -l `which java` lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2011-10-17
>   06:34 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java keith@KD-PB:~$ ls -l
>   /etc/alternatives/java lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 2011-10-17 06:34
>   /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/bin/gij-4.6
>
> keith@KD-PB:~$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
>   openjdk-6-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java

Comment: How did you install the Oracle JRE?.

Comment: I installed Oracle's Java via this PPA https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/java 

I try to avoid adding PPA's that I am not 100% about. I am still trying to get OpenJDK to work, but keep getting the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the java installations several times but nothing changed, it would only detect the gij java application, or none at all when that was removed. So the following workaround did it for me.

I added the the [Webupd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8) to my list of repo's and from their I installedhe application called 'update-java'. After installing I ran it update-java from the terminal, it went looking for the java I had installed, found it and then in a GUI asked me to pick which one to set as standard. After doing this I ran java-version from the terminal to confirm.

I can confirm it is working again and seems to be set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... It's weird that the OpenJDK is not working... I had several problems with it and Eclipse, so I had to put Java from Oracle. It works excellent. My suggest: don't install OpenJDK.